# Rearrange torch 2D tensors ("Tiles") to be in a particular order

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I have something that looks like this...

```
import torch
X = torch.cat([torch.ones((2,4)).unsqueeze(0), torch.ones((2,4)).unsqueeze(0)*2, torch.ones((2,4)).unsqueeze(0)*3, torch.ones((2,4)).unsqueeze(0)*4]).unsqueeze(0)
```

which is

```
tensor([[[[1., 1., 1., 1.],
          [1., 1., 1., 1.]],

         [[2., 2., 2., 2.],
          [2., 2., 2., 2.]],

         [[3., 3., 3., 3.],
          [3., 3., 3., 3.]],

         [[4., 4., 4., 4.],
          [4., 4., 4., 4.]]]])
```

And I want to rearrange them to look like this

```
tensor([[[1., 1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
         [1., 1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
         [3., 3., 3., 3., 4., 4., 4., 4.],
         [3., 3., 3., 3., 4., 4., 4., 4.]]])
```

However the solution I was hoping would work obviously doesn't and while I understand why it doesn't work I'll share it.

```
b, t, x, y = X.shape
num_x_splits = num_y_splits = 2
X = X.reshape(-1,x*num_x_splits,y*num_y_splits)
```

```
tensor([[[1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
         [2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
         [3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3.],
         [4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4.]]])
```

Is there a computationally efficient way I can accomplish what I want?

---

I did some more research and looks like the ideal solution might actually be a combinatoin of the accepted answer and to use the [einops](https://github.com/arogozhnikov/einops) package which provides a high-level, easy-to-read, efficient solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will start with the simple case where we know the number of tensors and which tensors to be positioned etc.:

```
ones = 1 * torch.ones(2,4)
twos = 2 * torch.ones(2,4)
thrs = 3 * torch.ones(2,4)
fors = 4 * torch.ones(2,4)
fivs = 5 * torch.ones(2,4)
sixs = 6 * torch.ones(2,4)
row1 = torch.cat([ones, twos], axis = 1)
row2 = torch.cat([thrs, fors], axis = 1)
row3 = torch.cat([fivs, sixs], axis = 1)
comb = torch.cat([row1, row2, row3], axis = 0)
print(comb)

tensor([[1., 1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
        [3., 3., 3., 3., 4., 4., 4., 4.],
        [3., 3., 3., 3., 4., 4., 4., 4.],
        [5., 5., 5., 5., 6., 6., 6., 6.],
        [5., 5., 5., 5., 6., 6., 6., 6.]])
```

So you just need to concatenate rows first then combine all rows on the axis=0 which will get the positioning as you want if you know which tensors you want to combine etc.

Another way to solve this is to permute the dimensions so that you get the placement you want which should work for more complex cases as well:

```
comb2 = torch.cat([ones, twos, thrs, fors, fivs, sixs]).view(3, 2, 2, 4)
print(comb2)
print(comb2.permute(0, 2, 1, 3). reshape(6, 8))

tensor([[[[1., 1., 1., 1.],
          [1., 1., 1., 1.]],

         [[2., 2., 2., 2.],
          [2., 2., 2., 2.]]],


        [[[3., 3., 3., 3.],
          [3., 3., 3., 3.]],

         [[4., 4., 4., 4.],
          [4., 4., 4., 4.]]],


        [[[5., 5., 5., 5.],
          [5., 5., 5., 5.]],

         [[6., 6., 6., 6.],
          [6., 6., 6., 6.]]]])
tensor([[1., 1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
        [3., 3., 3., 3., 4., 4., 4., 4.],
        [3., 3., 3., 3., 4., 4., 4., 4.],
        [5., 5., 5., 5., 6., 6., 6., 6.],
        [5., 5., 5., 5., 6., 6., 6., 6.]])
```

In the first view of the tensor, we view it such that we know we have 3 sets of tensors with 2x4 dimensions and each of these 2x4 tensors stored in additional dimension (2x2x4) to make it easier to manipulate instead of storing 2x8 or 4x4. Then we rearrange the dimensions to get the placement you want. I try to go backwards from the desired dimension to find the permutation I want usually. First dimension should then be 6 = 3x2 where we get 3 sets and 2 rows of tensor so we keep the first axis in place, move rows dimension next to set dimension: permute(**0, 2**, 1, 3). Permutation of 4 dimensional tensors can be a bit tricky to imagine, just play with it and you will get the right combination :)

Answer (score 5):

I accepted the correct answer but just wanted to share a more generic version of the code in case it helps anyone.

```
x, y = tile_x_dim, tile_y_dim   # for readability
X = X.reshape(-1, num_x_splits, num_y_splits, x, y)
X = X.permute(0,1,3,2,4).reshape(-1,x*num_x_splits,y*num_y_splits)
```

Where `tile_x_dim` and `tile_y_dim` are the x and y dimension respectively of the tile that was formed from the full image. `num_x_splits` and `num_y_splits` is the number of times the original picture was split along the x-axis. Note that `num_x_splits` multiplied by `num_y_splits` would give the number of tiles the image was cut into.

Answer (score 5):

You asked for einops one-liner? Here you go:

```
>>> from einops import rearrange

>>> x.shape  # x is taken from question.
torch.Size([1, 4, 2, 4])

>>> rearrange(x, '1 (i1 i2) j k -> (i1 j) (i2 k)', i1=2)
tensor([[1., 1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
        [3., 3., 3., 3., 4., 4., 4., 4.],
        [3., 3., 3., 3., 4., 4., 4., 4.]])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use NumPy's `block()` function to create block-matrices (and then convert to a tensor):

```py
import torch
import numpy as np

A = np.ones((2,4))
B = np.ones((2,4))*2
C = np.ones((2,4))*3
D = np.ones((2,4))*4

X = np.block([[A,B],
              [C,D]])

torch.tensor(X)
```

```
tensor([[1., 1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
        [3., 3., 3., 3., 4., 4., 4., 4.],
        [3., 3., 3., 3., 4., 4., 4., 4.]], dtype=torch.float64)
```

Comment: It's already a tensor so wouldn't converting the type back to numpy be pretty computationally inefficient relative to the already selected answer?

Comment: @financial_physician PyTorch tensors and numpy arrays [share the same memory locations](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/what-is-the-overhead-of-transforming-numpy-to-torch-and-vice-versa/7395) so this should be very efficient.

Comment: If this was done at training time, the tensor would be on the gpu so I'd have to move it from the gpu to the cpu and from the cpu back to the gpu... Would that add significant time?

Comment: @financial_physician that depends on the size of the matrices and how often you do this operation. You can test it out and see if it's practical.

Comment: They're huge images so in this case probably not the best strategy for this use case. It's good to know about though! Thanks for the insight :)

Comment: @financial_physician I may be wrong, but it sounds like you want to pre-process these images by putting the segment blocks together as one image. In that case, this shouldn't add much overhead if you do the 'blocking' as part of the preprocessing before passing the data to the model in the training loop itself.

Comment: I don't think so, we're replicating the "Toward Transformer-Based Object Detection" paper that came out in December by Pintrist. Figure 1 shows a nice outline of the architecture and the part where this is happening is "Reinterpret transformer patch outputs as a feature map". So at this point the patches were passed through the transformer having a specific shape and now it's time to aggregate them into an image-like object

Answer (score 1):

```
import torch
X = torch.cat([torch.ones((2,4)).unsqueeze(0), torch.ones((2,4)).unsqueeze(0)*3], dim = 1)
Y = torch.cat([torch.ones((2,4)).unsqueeze(0)*2, torch.ones((2,4)).unsqueeze(0)*4], dim = 1)
Z = torch.cat((X, Y), dim = 2)
print(Z)

tensor([[[1., 1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
         [1., 1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
         [3., 3., 3., 3., 4., 4., 4., 4.],
         [3., 3., 3., 3., 4., 4., 4., 4.]]])
```

Generally we avoid tensor to numpy conversions when we needed to use the tensor for Back-propagating. I think you can use this and its the exact dimensions you are looking for.